# Is there a way I could code a cipher that doesn't incorporated a space in the cipher?

Tags: python, encryption

I am coding a basic Caesar Cipher, which is almost finished, but has a small problem. When I run the code and it asks for the user's input, if the inputs any spaces, the program will include them in the cipher. I want to just pass it without encrypting.

This is the code -

```
#This is a working code encrypter and decrypter
#Created by Aykhan Salimov on 08.23.2020
#"s" specifies the number of the shift to encrypt
s = 3
text = input("Input text that you wish to be ciphered: ")
def cipherText(text,s):
    global result
    result = ""
    x = len(text) - text.count(" ")
    
    for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]
        if char.isupper():
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
    print("Ciphertext:", result)
#This is the decrypter
#"d" is the amount need to shift back
d = s * -1
#a is the variable used to use the encrypted code
def plainText(text,d,result):
    decrypt = ""
    for i in range(len(result)):
        char = result[i]
        if char.isupper():
            decrypt += chr((ord(char) + d - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            decrypt += chr((ord(char) + d - 97) % 26 + 97)
    print("Plaintext:", decrypt)
cipherText(text,s)
plainText(text,d,result)
```

This program does exactly what I want it to, but it isn't correctly able to exclude spaces from the cipher. I am a beginner programmer, and I really need help on creating my first cipher.

Comment: what is it that you want? to just ignore spaces or leave them there without encrypting them?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Use 'char.space()' in your encrypt and decrypt methods and 'result += char' AND as @Hilea commented leave out encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Michael Fehr, thank you for your, and @Hilea 's help, it was very useful, and helped mt program work! I understand as to why know! Thank you also for making me feel welcome:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if what you want is to just pass it without encrypting it you can do the following

```
for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]
        if char == " ":
            result += " "
            continue
        if char.isupper():
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
```

or if what you want is to completely remove it you can do `result += ""`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly the way I would like it to, and I now understand why this wasn't working earlier. Thank you for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your code:

We handle each of the three cases:

1. Uppercase
2. Lowercase
3. Non-letters, such as spaces

***What was the problem?***

Lowercase and non-letters were treated in the same condition of:

```
if char.isupper():
     <code>
# Here both space and lower-case were handeled
else:
    <code>
```

Example:

> Input text that you wish to be ciphered: Sabich dsF 
> Ciphertext: Vaelfk gvI 
> Plaintext: Sabich dsF

```
# This is a working code encrypter and decrypter
# Created by Aykhan Salimov on 08.23.2020
# "s" specifies the number of the shift to encrypt
s = 3
text = input("Input text that you wish to be ciphered: ")


def cipherText(text, s):
    global result
    result = ""
    x = len(text) - text.count(" ")

    for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]
        if 'a' < char < 'z':
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
        elif 'A' < char < 'Z':
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            result += char
    print("Ciphertext:", result)


# This is the decrypter
# "d" is the amount need to shift back
d = s * -1


# a is the variable used to use the encrypted code
def plainText(text, d, result):
    decrypt = ""
    for i in range(len(result)):
        char = result[i]
        if 'a' < char < 'z':
            decrypt += chr((ord(char) + d - 97) % 26 + 97)
        elif 'A' < char < 'Z':
            decrypt += chr((ord(char) + d - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            decrypt += char
    print("Plaintext:", decrypt)


cipherText(text, s)
plainText(text, d, result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works very well, but I do not understand what was wrong with my code. I would much appreciate it if you could clarify the changes.

Comment: @AykhanSalimov added more explanation :) Let me know if you find it useful

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying! This was very useful, and I can see my issue now:)

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote, but I would:). The one I have just marked as solved, is a bit shorter. Is it possible to mark two comments as solved? I'm new here, so I don't know much:(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove spaces from input, You can use `replace()`:

```
string = string.replace(" ","") #Replace space
```

Input:

```
Hi Aykhan
```

Output:

```
HiAykhan
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I was not asking to remove the spaces. My problem is that when the code ciphers, and de-ciphers, in between each word it inserts a letter